# Regex: Replace unknown number of occurances after a given marker

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to figure out a way of replacing a `/` with `-` in the GET part of a href tag in a html file looking like this:

```
blah blah <a href="aaaaa/aaaaa/aaaaa/?q=43/23"> blah blah <a
href="aaaaa/aaaaa/aaaaa/?q=43/11/1"> blah blah blah
```

So basically I'm looking to make the two URLs end with `?q=43-23` and `?q=43-11-1` respectively.

How can I do this with a `preg_replace`? I can obviously get the `43/23` to be `43-23` with

```
/(\?.+?)\/(.+?)$/is
```

And I can get `43/11/1` to be `43-11-1` with

```
/(\?.+?)\/(.+?)\/(.+?)$/is
```

But how can I do this in a single regex taking into account that there may be an unlimited number of slashes after the `?`.  Any suggestions or someone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can the url (slashes) also break across lines?

Comment: don't do this. use a DOM parser to extract the href attributes, then process each one individually.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a recursive pattern to accomplish this.

Comment: There's no way to capture each group individually with a single regex if the group repeats

Comment: >don't do this. use a DOM parser to extract the href attributes, then process each one individually

Yes I know.  The reason I'm not doing that is that the scope of the job is very limited and I know the HTML files coming in is formatted in a certain way.  Since I need the original HTML with just this modification, it seems like a unnecessary step to unpack into DOM, then modify and then repack as HTML (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be easy for your content;

```
print preg_replace_callback('~\?q=([^&"]*)~', function($m) {
    return '?q='. str_replace('/', '-', $m[1]);
}, $s);
// for PHP < 5.3.0
print preg_replace_callback('~\?q=([^&"]*)~', create_function(
    '$m', 'return "?q=". str_replace("/", "-", $m[1]);'
), $s);
```

Out;

```
blah blah <a href="aaaaa/aaaaa/aaaaa/?q=43-23"> blah blah <a
href="aaaaa/aaaaa/aaaaa/?q=43-11-1"> blah blah blah
blah blah  blah blah  blah blah blah
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This seems to have done the trick.  Selected as answer, because it did the trick with the least amount of hassle (it also made some presumptions regarding the text structure that was not apparent from my question, but happened to be right :) ).    Thank you so much.  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the simplest search and replace because of how regex engines handle repeated capture groups.  [Applying repeated capture group principles](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), you can use the regex to capture the repeating group and then do a simple string replace.

```
preg_replace_callback('/
    (      # start capture
       \?  # question mark
       .+? # reluctantly capture all until...
    )      # end capture
    (      # start capture
    (?:    # start group (no capture)
       \/  # ...a literal slash
       .+? # reluctantly capture all until...
    )      # end group
    +      # repeat capture group
    )      # end capture
    (      # start capture
    \b     # ...a word boundary
    )      # end capture
    /isx', function ($matches) {
   return $matches[1] . str_replace('/', '-', $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, $str));
```

You do the string replace on the second match which is the repeated group capture.  The word boundary at the end is necessary, but it can be replaced with something more sensible or correct such as `"` (if you know the URL ends here), or even `("|')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match an unlimited amount of (slash) levels after the query parameter *q=*.

```
// Using tilde delimiters because hash signs are interpreted as comments here :)
~q=((?:[^/]+|/|)*)$~i
```

For example with the string *"aaaaa/aaaaa/aaaaa/?q=43/11/1/5/10"* the first captured group will contain **43/11/1/5/10**.

Afterwards you can do the following to replace slashes with hyphens:

```
<?php str_replace( '/', '-', $string );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Very much appreciated.  I may be a bit slow, but how could I use this two-step technique to replace the original HTML file?  Yours preg_match works brilliantly to extract the query string, and I can of course as you say use str_replace to modify that bit after I extract it.  But how would I "get it back in" to the HTML file again.  Only method I can think of is storing the original extract, and then looping through the file for each extract replacing it with the modified query.  Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Hm, I was assuming you're doing just for individual links not complete HTML documents. If that is the case then you should follow @MarcB's advice and use a HTML parser to find all the links, then you can modify them safely.